# Querying for tickets with unclosed blockers

Tags: redmine

I'm trying to work with Redmine custom queries and I cannot find a way to create a custom query that will find all issues with unclosed blockers. I can query for issues with any blockers, but that will also find issues with closed blockers. That doesn't match what I think of when I think of a "blocked issue". Blocked issues are issues with open blockers.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This apparently has been added in the most recent version 3.2.0 per http://www.redmine.org/issues/16621.